# Is there a way to "Regenerate Feature files" for SpecFlow tests from the command line?

Tags: powershell, command-line, specflow

For SpecFlow based test projects, there is a command called "Regenerate Feature Files" on the project context menu (right click) that will (as the name implies) regenerate the backing code for the feature files of SpecFlow tests.  I am automating as much of our process as possible and I would like to be able to call this command from the command line, preferably powershell on a build and/or deploy server.

Is there a way for me to call this action from the command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

By command line: http://www.specflow.org/documentation/Tools/

By MsBuild: http://www.specflow.org/documentation/Generate-Tests-from-MsBuild/